# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type (nodes)

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Hey so I'm getting that error whenever I try to do something like this:

```
void swap(struct lnode* n1){
    struct lnode*temp = n1->next;
}
```

I thought that I could have the temp pointer point to n1->next but it's giving me the dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access members of the struct a declaration like this is insufficient:

```
struct lnode;
```

This gives you an incomplete type: the compiler now knows the name of the struct but doesn't know what fields it contains. You can have pointers to incomplete types, but you can't access their members, calculate their sizes, or do anything else that requires knowledge of the structure members.

A full definition is required. As in:

```
struct lnode
{
    struct lnode *next;
    /* other fields */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the full declaration of `struct lnode` in scope. Otherwise, how will
the compiler know where to find the `next` member?

Comment: Not necessarily inside the class, but you'll need the full declaration available at the point where you reference `next` or other members, or need to know the size of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You question suggests that the compiler does not have visibility of what lnode is i.e. not the full picture of struct lnode.  May be you can post a bit more of your code for us to help out.